# Manga in which the main character wakes up years after sacrificing himself in a dungeon (if I'm not mistaken) and being abandoned by his party

Tags: story-identification, manga

What I remember is that the main character (MC) fights against the demon lord/demon(?) with his party. The MC almost dies after sacrificing himself, and is abandoned by his party because they think he is dead.

Years later, the MC wakes up and comes back to town, and finds the saint(?) married to one of the party members. The MC looks happy, but saint seems unhappy in her marriage, preferring the MC to her husband. He does meet the other party members at their wedding and they recognize him. The MC went to the wedding with another girl that he met at a market.

I think that this is not a revenge story.

Chapter 1, in my opinion, has similarities with the manga *Koko wa Ore ni Makasete Saki ni Ike to Itte kara 10-nen ga Tattara Densetsu ni Natte Ita.*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you explain what you meant by the following sentence (particularly the part in bold)...? It feels like an incomplete sentence as currently written. _"The mc looks happy, **but saint doesn't seem like.**"_

Comment: the saint seem like forced marry one of the member party, looks like saint prefers mc

Comment: Was the mc in a relationship with the saint before he was abandoned by his party? And did he want revenge afterwards?

Comment: sorry, i can't remember it, and i think there is no revenge

Comment: im not sure the woman is saint or not

Comment: You mentioned the mc being abandoned by his party. Were they happy to abandon him, or were they loyal friends who were reluctant to leave him?

Comment: He was definitely involved in fighting the demon lord? "Sono Mono. Nochi ni" involves the childhood friend saintess fighting against the demon lord and promptly being claimed by the hero... but the MC wasn't involved in this at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if that counts as abandoned, the party thinks the mc is dead so yeah....

Comment: @qazmlpok sorry i think "Sono Mono. Nochi ni" doesn't seem like it. thank you

Comment: He's not *actually* dead and wakes up as an undead monster of some sort, is he? Did you only read the first chapter? Any idea what happens after this?

Comment: yes, he didn't really die but he didn't become undead, because his party members/friends recognized him

Comment: I only remember until MC met his party members/friends at the wedding. ouh, when mc went to a wedding he went with a woman he met in the market

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it out and, to be honest, you gave a weird explain of how chapter 1 went, which was really different from what you said because it started with the main character (Sakuya) as a teen (he got transformed into a teen because of the magic fruits he ate in chapter 2/3) already helping the one of the female main characters. So actually, what you were referring to was chapter 2 and that made me a bit confused about which one it could be, but after several hours of intense searching, I guess I found it:

***[En no Shita no Chikaramocher ~Maou Toubatsu shitara Wakagaetta node, Gakuen de Kage kara Support shimasu~](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/lyflwv1)***.

[image: Promotional art for "En no Shita no Chikaramocher."]

Enjoy it, if it was the one you were looking for.

Comment: thank you very much bro, sorry, I thought it was in the first chapter

Comment: @uangreceh If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the asker's satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the following title?

The Former Hero Wants To Live Peacefully /
Moto yūsha wa shizuka ni kurashitai /
Moto Yuusha wa Shizuka ni Kurashitai /
元勇者は静かに暮らした

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't seem like it

Comment: thank you......

Comment: I can't find a single legitimate link to that manga :-)

Answer (score 0):

This manga? ***[I Became a Legend a Decade Later After Telling my Comrades to Leave Everything to Me and Retreat First](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ypv1hu3/koko-wa-ore-ni-makasete-saki-ni-ike-to-itte-kara-10-nen-ga-tattara-densetsu-ni-natte-ita)***.

> With no other options, Luck makes the choice to hold the line against the unending demonic hordes alone, to make sure his comrades can escape with their lives. However, through a combination of fortune, skill, and ingenuity, he holds that line for ten straight years, eventually coming out on top singlehandedly. Now he has to tackle the dilemma of how to occupy himself in a world where he holds a myriad of roles: that of a legend, that of a veteran, and that of a brand-new face.

[image: Promotional art for "I Became a Legend a Decade Later After Telling my Comrades to Leave Everything to Me and Retreat First."]

Comment: I don't think it's this one. I've read some of it, and while the MC does get trapped in a cave for years after telling his friends to leave and save themselves, I don't recall anything about a friend marrying a saint, or the MC attending their wedding. Also, the OP has already marked [SouldKing's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/280286/122024) as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), as denoted by the green tick next to that answer.